# JupyterLab does not adopt changes in a function from an imported script

Tags: python, function, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm using JupyterLab to run the script for analysing my data. In this script, called 'analysis.ipynb', I'm using a function out of the script  'def_readfb_dwd.py'. This function contained a little error (a wrong parameter 'conf_flag_fb_aeolus' was included) which I corrected. But the correction has not been adopted... when I run the analysis script again I got the same error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-39237ed9c16d> in <module>
----> 1 data_dwd = read_multiple_files(file_list,date_list,time_list,channel)
      2 print(channel + ': ' + data_str, + ' ---> data loaded')

~/PhD/code/functions/def_readfb_dwd.py in read_multiple_files(file_list, date_list, time_list, retrtype)
    106 
    107 def read_multiple_files(file_list,date_list,time_list,retrtype):
--> 108     combined_data = readin_fb_files(file_list[0],date_list[0],time_list[0],retrtype)
    109     if len(file_list)>1:
    110         for f in range(1,len(file_list)):

~/PhD/code/functions/def_readfb_dwd.py in readin_fb_files(file, d, anatime, retrtype)
     80     ### filter data for time and status-active
     81     filter_retrtype = np.where((data['retrtype'] == retrtype))[0]
---> 82     filter_flags = np.where((data['r_state'] == 1) & (data['r_check'] == 32))[0]
     83     filt_ind = np.intersect1d(filter_retrtype,filter_flags)
     84     data['r_state']=data['r_state'][filt_ind]

NameError: name 'conf_flag_fb_aeolus' is not defined
```

What can I do that changes in scripts, which I import are taken on

Comment: Did you rerun the import statement for the external script again (i.e., the cell with the relevant `import` statement)?

Comment: yes, I did rerun ' from 'def_readfb_dwd import * '

Comment: If you don't have data that you want to keep in your current session, you can try and restart the kernel.